# Should I write TypeScript definitions for my TypeScript module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am the process of writing my first TypeScript-based NPM module. When I am done, it will be exported through `"main"` in `package.json`, and this field will point at the compiled, plain javascript.

So when I require this module in another TypeScript module, IntelliSense and type checking will not work for my module, right?

So one solution would be to add a definition file. But definition files are for JS libs, right? It shouldn't be necessary to write a definition file for a TS project, right?

So... how am I going to export my definitions along with my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I just need to add `"declaration": true` to my `tsconfig.json`. Pretty simple.